# "Register" Virtual Box VM without GUI

Tags: linux, server, virtualbox

I created a VirtualbBox VM and want to move it to a Linux Server without GUI. So where do I have to copy the VM and what are the vboxmanage commands to register the VM. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it anywhere you like, since you are going to tell `VirtualBox` where it is anyway, with a command like this

```
VBoxManage registervm /path/to/YourVM.vdi
```